# typoscript overwrite tt_content.image.20.layout

Tags: typo3, typoscript

i want to set some classes on a textpic / image element.

css_styled_content is loaded and i want to overwrite tt_content.image.20.layout.

The typoscript that i tried and not work (copied from the org setup.txt):

```
tt_content.image.20 {
layout = CASE
    layout {
        key.field = imageorient
        # above-center
        default = TEXT
        default.value = <div class="adasd csc-textpic csc-textpic-center csc-textpic-above###CLASSES###">###IMAGES######TEXT###</div>
        # above-right
        1 = TEXT
        1.value = <div class="asd csc-textpic csc-textpic-right csc-textpic-above###CLASSES###">###IMAGES######TEXT###</div>
        # above-left
        2 = TEXT
        2.value = <div class=" asd csc-textpic csc-textpic-left csc-textpic-above###CLASSES###">###IMAGES######TEXT###</div>
        # below-center
        8 = TEXT
        8.value = <div class="asd csc-textpic csc-textpic-center csc-textpic-below###CLASSES###">###TEXT######IMAGES###</div>
        # below-right
        9 = TEXT
        9.value = <div class="asd csc-textpic csc-textpic-right csc-textpic-below###CLASSES###">###TEXT######IMAGES###</div>
        # below-left
        10 = TEXT
        10.value = <div class="asd csc-textpic csc-textpic-left csc-textpic-below###CLASSES###">###TEXT######IMAGES###</div>
        # intext-right
        17 = TEXT
        17.value = <div class="asd csc-textpic csc-textpic-intext-right###CLASSES###">###IMAGES######TEXT###</div>
        # intext-left
        18 = TEXT
        18.value = <div class="asd csc-textpic csc-textpic-intext-left###CLASSES###">###IMAGES######TEXT###</div>
        # intext-right-nowrap
        25 = TEXT
        25.value = <div class="asd csc-textpic csc-textpic-intext-right-nowrap###CLASSES###">###IMAGES######TEXT###</div>
        # intext-left-nowrap
        26 = TEXT
        26.value = <div class="asd csc-textpic csc-textpic-intext-left-nowrap###CLASSES###">###IMAGES######TEXT###</div>
    }
}
```

But the output on the frontend is:

```
<div class="csc-textpic csc-textpic-center csc-textpic-above">...</div>
```

What is wrong? :D
In the T3-Object-Browser seems all okay. But it not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why, but this works...

```
tt_content.textpic.20.default {
    layout = CASE
    layout {
        key.field = imageorient
        # above-center
        default = TEXT
        default.value = <div class="adasd csc-textpic csc-textpic-center csc-textpic-above###CLASSES###">###IMAGES######TEXT###</div>
        # above-right
        1 = TEXT
        1.value = <div class="asd csc-textpic csc-textpic-right csc-textpic-above###CLASSES###">###IMAGES######TEXT###</div>
        # above-left
        2 = TEXT
        2.value = <div class=" asd csc-textpic csc-textpic-left csc-textpic-above###CLASSES###">###IMAGES######TEXT###</div>
        # below-center
        8 = TEXT
        8.value = <div class="asd csc-textpic csc-textpic-center csc-textpic-below###CLASSES###">###TEXT######IMAGES###</div>
        # below-right
        9 = TEXT
        9.value = <div class="asd csc-textpic csc-textpic-right csc-textpic-below###CLASSES###">###TEXT######IMAGES###</div>
        # below-left
        10 = TEXT
        10.value = <div class="asd csc-textpic csc-textpic-left csc-textpic-below###CLASSES###">###TEXT######IMAGES###</div>
        # intext-right
        17 = TEXT
        17.value = <div class="asd csc-textpic csc-textpic-intext-right###CLASSES###">###IMAGES######TEXT###</div>
        # intext-left
        18 = TEXT
        18.value = <div class="asd csc-textpic csc-textpic-intext-left###CLASSES###">###IMAGES######TEXT###</div>
        # intext-right-nowrap
        25 = TEXT
        25.value = <div class="asd csc-textpic csc-textpic-intext-right-nowrap###CLASSES###">###IMAGES######TEXT###</div>
        # intext-left-nowrap
        26 = TEXT
        26.value = <div class="asd csc-textpic csc-textpic-intext-left-nowrap###CLASSES###">###IMAGES######TEXT###</div>
    }
}
```